# AS3:Calling a switch case from another class does't work

Tags: actionscript-3, class, function, flash-cs5, switch-statement

i am making a game in flash and the problem that i am having is with two classes a class called Menu for the welcome screen which has a startgame button and the engine class which runs everything when i run the game for the first time i set the menu to appear automatically by this code:

```
    public var state:int;
    public const MENU:int = 0;
    public const GAME:int = 1;
    // create the variable for the menu
    private var _menu:Menu;

    public var sBg1:ScrollBg;
    public var sBg2:ScrollBg;
    public function Engine(menu:Menu) 
    {

        _menu = menu;
        //we add event listener when the engine is added to the stage
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
    }
    private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
        //then we remove the event listener and initiate the init function
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

        init();
    }
    private function init():void {
        //the init function set the game state at first to menu and run the drawUI function
        state = MENU;
        drawUI();

    }

    public function drawUI():void 
    {
        //the drawUI function draw the needed elements on stage according to the state of the game
        switch(state){
            case MENU:
                _menu = new Menu();
                addChild(_menu);
                break;
            case GAME:
                sBg1= new ScrollBg();   
                addChild(sBg1);
                sBg1.x = 0;
                sBg1.y = 0;
                //if(contains(_menu)){
                //removeChild(_menu);}

                trace('this the game');
                break;
                    }
    }
```

and i change the state from menu to the actual game using this code in the menu class:

```
    public var start_btn:MovieClip;
    private var _engine:Engine;
    public function Menu() 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, displayMenu);
    }

    private function displayMenu(e:Event):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, displayMenu);
        start_btn = new startBtn();
        start_btn.x = 100;
        start_btn.y = 200;
        addChild(start_btn);
        start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
    }

    private function startGame(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        start_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        _engine = new Engine(this);
        _engine.state = 1;
        _engine.drawUI();
    }
```

i use the drawUI function each time for the menu for example it places the start button and for the game it places the background but for some reason i only get the trace statement saying (this the game) but the background is not displayed any clues .

i spend more then 4 hours trying to find out what is the problem and i still can't if anyone can help me that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please comment your code and explain what the mystery objects are.

Comment: Also, please show a more complete class in the code (e.g., `class Menu extends ...`).

Comment: The background is (probably) being added.  Add a `trace()` that verifies the wid/ht, x/y, and visibility of `sBg1`.  Finally, add a `trace(this.getChildIndex(sBg1))`.  This should all go in the relevant switch command.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the trace but nothing on screen that is most likely because the ScrollBg class doesn't have anything to display. Make sure that class has some sprites or images in it.

Comment: the class is linked to a movieclip in my library which contains the background